# Persisting scroll position when changing segment control in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am using segment control in my home page. When ever I am changing segment it is reloading scroll view. I am looking something like addChild or removeChild in UIKit option so that my scroll position will not change.

```
struct HomeListView:View {
    @State private var favoriteColor = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("What is your favorite color?", selection: $favoriteColor) {
                Text("Red").tag(0)
                Text("Green").tag(1)
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 8, trailing: 8))
            selectedView
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder var selectedView: some View {
        switch favoriteColor {
        case 0:
            HomeViewListing()
        default:
            TestListingView()
        }
    }
    
    
}


struct HomeViewListing:View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
             LazyVStack {
                 ForEach(0..<100) { item in
                     Text("\(item)")
                 }
             }
         }
         .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
    }
}
struct TestListingView:View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
             LazyVStack {
                 ForEach(0..<100) { item in
                     Text("\(item)")
                 }
             }
         }
         .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
    }
}
```

Steps to reproduce

1)Scroll HomeListingView item to 98

2)Change segment control( to TestListingView)

3)Change segment control again(to HomeListingView)

Scroll position is changed now to 0 but it should be at position 98(step 1 )

Comment: No solution found yet. i think there is something related to pages added.